# Can I read hardware counters in android?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to read cache hardware counters to optimize my android application but I dont know how to do this.

Is any function or library in NDK to access to this counters?

Also, I have tried to compile PAPI (http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/) library but I don't know how to do this with Android NDK.

My terminal is a Nexus 5 with a Snapdragon 800 processor (model: 8974-AA).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't provide any functionality to access `Performance Management Unit / PMU` and it is not required to be part of any Android release from any vendor.

Your best guess might be to build [linux-tools-perf](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/linux-tools-perf/) available from Android repository but even in that case you can't use it on a non-rooted phone.